# Hapi js export server variable

Tags: node.js, tdd, hapi.js

I want to add tests to my project. The server is written in Hapi and I was wondering where to put my tests folder and how to export the server variable to the tests file. I know I can export it with `module.exports = server` but I think it's not a good idea to export it like that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can look at  [here](https://hapijs.com/resources#Gists-and-code-samples) I found a lot of examples to structure my projects.

Comment: There is a lot there but this answer is not very specific nor helpful to me.